# Winforms list display options?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am building a WinForms program that connects to a DB. On one form I want to display a list of elements recovered from the DB. The elements have to be clickable (radio buttons are an option here), and must have a hover option, as I want some info to appear in a textbox when mouse is hovered over a specific item.

I cannot find an adequate ToolBox control for this. Has anyone got some suggestions? I am using VS2010.

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to capture the OnMouseEnter, OnMouseHover and OnMouseExit Event to show and hide a control etc    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no such ready-to-use control in .net framework instead you have to `design/create` your own using [Window custom controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using a standard `ListBox`, you can just track the mouse position with the `MouseMove` event.

Example:

```
int _HoverIndex = -1;

private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);

  if (index != _HoverIndex) {       
    _HoverIndex = index;

    if (_HoverIndex == -1)
      textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    else
      textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[_HoverIndex].ToString();
  }
}

private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  _HoverIndex = -1;
  textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```